# How to set default gnome-classic and root user on gdm (OpenSuse Leap 42.2)

Tags: opensuse, root, gdm, gnome-classic

I'm using my linux only managed by root user (I know is not the best practice).

The first point is, since beginning, my *gdm* is not showing root user on the initial list, so there is not available users on initial list. How can I set root to appear on the list or selected by default?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about. It only shows "Is not on the list?" (sorry, screenshots are in spanish), so I must click there to type root.

[image: sc1]

The second point is, I want to use *gnome-classic* by default but now I must select it always and it is not remembering last login. I read it should remember... is because is root user? How can I put *gnome-classic* as default environment?

[image: sc2]

I tried so many things... editing `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/root` and putting `XSession=gnome-classic`

This is the content of my `/usr/share/xsessions` dir:

```
gnome-classic.desktop  icewm-session.desktop  sle-classic.desktop
gnome.desktop          icewm.desktop          xsession.desktop
```

So the *gnome-classic* is there... I don't know how to make it work as default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me on SLES 15:

```
rm -f /usr/share/xsessions/default.desktop
ln -s /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/default.desktop
```